# Shortcuts to resize windows

Tags: 18.04, window-manager, resize, tiling

I've just installed Ubuntu 18.04 and I'm wondering if there's a way to set shortcuts for commonly/frequently used resizing and positioning of the windows.

My other laptop is a Macbook and I use [Magnet](https://magnet.crowdcafe.com/) to quickly resize and reposition windows. Using Magnet I can quickly hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> to snap a window to the upper half of the screen at 100% width, or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> to snap it to the right half of the screen with 100% height. This is the kind of UX I'm after.

My window manager is GDM3.

```
$ cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager
/usr/sbin/gdm3
```

Is there a way to do this with GDM3? or is there an application I can install that will enable it? Or should I switch GDM3 for another window manager? I'm open to options here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build-in tiling shortcuts include:

- <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> to maximize
- <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> to restore
- <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> to tile left half
- <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> to tile right half

You can see more options and assign shortcuts to them by looking into settings that by default are not exposed. Install `dconf-editor`.  Navigate to /org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/ to find several window-manager related shortcuts. You will find options such as "maximize-horizontally" and "maximize-vertically" among other options, where you can set a key binding. Look at examples where a keybinding is defined to learn about the syntax to define a keybinding.

Comment: Thank you. This is useful. Can't seem to find a simple way to tile to the top/bottom half though. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: No, I see no options to achieve that in dconf-editor.